# Filling Java Forms with nested objects

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm working on a project with has a webservice server and Play!2.0 as the webapp. Both share a JAR file with models which are POJO. No JPA, no other relations. I just map them to Mongo Objects.
All fields are public and only overloads are on toString to ease debugging.

Now I want fill a form in Play with a object loaded from the webservice.

```
Dispatch preDispatch= patientCardsService.getGetDispatch(name, surname, null);
Form<Dispatch> dispatchForm = form(Dispatch.class).fill(preDispatch);
return ok(patientCard.render(dispatchForm ));
```

At the field i've got something like this.

```
@(dForm: Form[Common.Models.Dispatch ])

@mainMobile("Card") {  

@jqmInput(dForm("status"), "Status")
@jqmInput(dForm("patientData.name"), "Name")
@jqmInput(dForm("patientData.surname"), "Surname")
}
```

The Dispatch object ofcourse contains the PatientData object which contains name and surname strings.
And the jqmInput is a helper

```
@(field: Field, label: String, fieldType: Symbol = 'text)
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
    <label for="@field.id" class="ui-input-text" class="ui-input-text">@label</label>
    <input type="@fieldType.name" value="@field.value" name="@field.id" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"/>
</div>
```

And this isn't filled with the object.
I've checked and the object prior to fill is populated.

Anybody knows what is a cause of this?

Comment: Nested forms are possible with Scala https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms#Nested-values. With Java, it seems to be possible too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25645751/873282 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759163/play-framework-2-java-form-data-binding-with-nested-allowed-fields