# Play framework 2 (Java) form data binding with nested allowed fields

Tags: java, playframework, spring-data, playframework-2.3

Consider following model:

```
public class Contact {

  @Required
  public String name;

  @Valid
  public List<Information> informations;

  }

  public static class Information {

    public String securedField;

    @Required
    public String email;

    @Valid
    public List<Phone> phones;

    public static class Phone {

      @Required
      @Pattern(value = "[0-9.+]+", message = "A valid phone number is required")
      public String number;
    }

  }

}
```

I don't want `Information securedField` to be affected by [mass assignment vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_assignment_vulnerability). So i decided to set array of allowedFields for `Contact Form`.

As i know, [play forms are based on Spring DataBinder](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/data/Form.java#L308), so is it possible to handle collection fields? I don't want to write smth like:

- name
- informations[0].email
- informations[0].phones*
- informations[1].email
- informations[1].phones*
- etc

Following doesn't work:

- name
- informations.email
- informations.phones*

Should i extend existing `Spring DataBinder` and `Form` classes and override `bind` method in this case?

Comment: What populates the `securedField` attribute? Is it an immutable field that can only be set at creation time? If so, maybe a JPA annotation on the field can help.

Comment: @avik, user with specific role, for example admin, can have ability to fill it. So for this user list of allowed fields will include securedField (or even all fields).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an arguably simpler solution. How about defining an extra constraint that will trigger a validation failure if the POST data contains any `informations[%d].securedField` values?

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Null;

public static class Information {

    @Null
    public String securedField;

    ...

}
```

I think that this way you can call the default `bindFromRequest` method instead of the one that accepts a whitelist of form field names, and still be protected against a mass assignment attack.

One shortcoming with this approach admittedly is that it would ultimately leak the names of your internal fields in the event of a concerted mass assignment attack. However if they had fairly bland, meaningless names such as `securedField` (no offence intended!), I'm not sure how this information could be exploited by an attacker.

### Edit

If you want to allow assignment to the field based on the current user type, maybe bean validation groups could help:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Null;

public class Contact {

    public interface Administrator {}

    public interface User {}

    ...

    public class Information {

        @Null(groups = User.class)
        public String securedField;

        ...

    }

}
```

#### Controller code

```
...
final Form<Contact> contactForm;
if (currentUser.isAdministrator()) {
    contactForm = form(Contact.class, Administrator.class).bindFromRequest();
} else {
    contactForm = form(Contact.class, User.class).bindFromRequest();
}
...
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good way, sorry. In some cases securedField should be filled.

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood the problem. I'll post a comment on your question to fish for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the following patterns to whitelist nested collection fields:

```
informations[*].email
informations[*].phones[*].*
```

i.e.

```
form.bindFromRequest("name", "informations[*].email", "informations[*].phones[*].*");
```