# play form bindrequest to map

Tags: json, playframework

```
"guards": 
{
    "monday": {
        "name": "steven",
        "age": 18
    },
    "sunday": {
        "name": "joe",
        "age": 21
    }
}
Form<TestForm> testForm = myForms.form(TestForm.class).bindFromRequest();
```

suppose the format is that way, i thought of binding them to a class of `Map<String,Object>` would work, but it just won't bind. when I check the map object size it would return 0.

in Play 2.5 Java, how would you take sunday,monday as String key and value is object that has name and age as its property?

Comment: i guess it's Play Java?

Comment: also, add more details about what you did, and why it didn't work

Comment: @pedrorijo91 i thought i was pretty clear about binding them into a form object and resulting the object's size is 0

Comment: This could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759163/play-framework-2-java-form-data-binding-with-nested-allowed-fields